# Why i don't see anything on the map of pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing pokemon go for one week, everything was fine. Suddenly i am seeing a no items on map. No gyms, no pokemons and no poke stops. Checked reinstalling the game but no luck.
Can anyone suggest how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: After your location is determined with GPS, i'm pretty sure the map and the objects on it are downloaded using your data connection. Have you checked to make sure your internet is working fine?

Comment: Do you have any screenshots that you could add to the question to give us some kind of idea to what's actually going on to your game?

Comment: Hi Todd Wilcox, Yes my internet is working fine. Even i am able to move and download the map but no other items are showing up.

Comment: Hi Riftcaster, iam unable to add any screenshot here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your gps and (especially) mobile data connection are working properly. The times when item stops don't show up on my map are either when my data connection has issues or the server has issues.

Comment: It was working perfectly till yesterday, but I don't see any items on my map today.